# Finding pyspark StreamingContext state

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

So I'm using another pyspark program to control when the `StreamingContext` starts and stops executing its streams. At the same time I'm trying to get this program to run:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: <fileName> <appId>")

    appId = sys.argv[1] 
    context = None

    for ssc in StreamingContext.getActive():
        if ssc.sparkContext.applicationId == appId:
            context = ssc
            break
    else:
        sys.exit("No StreamingContext found with matching appId")

    #while context has started but not stopped
        print("StreamingContext is working, writing data to stream.")
        #write data to stream
```

I'm able to find the `context` that my other program created, the problem is I don't if it has started or stopped. `awaitTermination()` doesn't seem to work in this case since I want to continuously check the state of `context` rather than to let the program hang. Is there anyway for me to do this?

I'm using:

Python 3.6

PySpark 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer was less complicated than I thought. `context == StreamingContext.getActive()` should do.